# No se carga correctamente hoja de estilos

Tags: css, http, https, estilos

tengo el siguiente problema, si accedo a la página con **https:** se levanta una hoja de estilos pero si la cargo con **http** se levanta otra hoja de estilos (la hoja de estilo que estaba antes).
La página es [www.ghostyu2.com.ar](http://www.ghostyu2.com.ar).
Observar los estilos que se muestran en la cabecera cargando la web de una u otra manera.
Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

*Lo siguiente es un comentario, no pude evitarlo, y aún me falta puntos para poder comentar tu publicación original, así que los moderadores discúlpenme.*

Parece que tienes un problema de Cache, puedes realizar las siguientes acciones:

1. A tu vista que hace el llamado a la hoja de estilos, actualízala, por ejemplo si la hoja de estilos es "estilos" ahora renómbrala y llámala e.g. "estilos_v001", esto hará que tu navegador descargue la hoja, que yo recuerde se suele "versionar" los archivos que invoca una vista para evitar los problemas de cache.
2. Borra el cache o datos almacenado de la web en tu Navegador, también puedes entrar en modo incognito, en el modo desarrollador también tienes la opción de deshabilitar el cache.

Espero haberte ayudado, repito esto es más como un comentario.

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego. Vos sabés que estoy seguro que a eso que indicás lo hice, por supuesto que también borré la caché 1000 veces porque creía que era eso, pero no pasaba nada. Incluso hasta eliminé el css en el servidor, lo cual efectivamente provocaba que no se carguen los estilos, pero cuando volvía a subir el css, resulta que mostraba una versión vieja del mismo para https y una nueva versión para http. Parece mentira pero es lo que pasaba, me estaba volviendo loco. Ahora accedí de nuevo y se muestran para uno y otro el mismo css. Muchas gracias Diego.